# Max value and item in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

In this list of tuples, I wish to fetch `max` float value and its correspondent string:

```
tuples = [(0, u'nope1'), (0.006535947712418301, u'target'), (0, u'nope2'),
          (0, u'nope3')]
```

If I:

```
map(max,zip(*tuples))
```

it prints:

```
[0.006535947712418301, u'nope3']
```

but I need:

```
[0.006535947712418301, u'target']
```

How?

Comment: `list(max(tuples))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tuples = [(0, u'nope1'), (0.006535947712418301, u'target'), (0, u'nope2'), (0, u'nope3')]

print(max(tuples))
```

will give the answer

Answer (score 0):

I try simply

```
max(tuples)
```

and it works.